# Procurar mínimo de uma lista ignorando valores zero

Tags: python, python-2.7

Eu tenho uma lista de valores com elementos zero e elementos diferentes de zero e queria retornar o menor valor da lista e respetivo indice, mas ignorando os zeros, ou seja, o facto de haver zeros não significa que seja o menor valor mas simplesmente que não é para ser lido.

Assim numa lista deste género: `B=[6, 9, 4, 0, 7, 10, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 11]` eu queria que retornasse o valor 2 e neste caso o índice 6.

Tentei fazer:

```
for a in range(0,len(B)):
    if (B[a]!=0 and B[a]<B[a+1]):
        b_min=B[a]
        indice=a
```

Mas não dá o que pretendo.

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
menorNumero = min(numero for numero in B if numero != 0)
indiceDoMenorNumero = B.index(menorNumero)
```

Estou aplicando a função `min`, que pega o menor valor de uma lista, a uma expressão geradora (também funcionaria com uma *list comprehension*). Essa expressão pode ser lida como "todos os números da lista B diferentes de zero".

A função `index` é usada para pegar a posição da primeira ocorrência do número.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se essa é a melhor forma, mas foi o que consegui fazer com o pouco de tempo que tive sem usar as funções `min` e `index`

```
def menorDiferenteDeZero(lista):
    menorValorIndex = -1

    for i in range(0, len(lista)):
        if(menorValorIndex == -1 or (lista[i] < lista[menorValorIndex]) and lista[i] != 0):
            menorValorIndex = i

    if menorValorIndex == -1:
        print("A lista nao contem elementos diferentes de zero")
        return

    print 'Menor index eh o {0} que tem como valor {1}'.format(menorValorIndex, lista[menorValorIndex])

lista = [6, 9, 4, 0, 7, 10, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 11]
menorDiferenteDeZero(lista)
```

Comment: Ambos funcionam, muito obrigada!!!

Answer (score 0):

Outra abordagem, sem recorrer a funções internas, seria:

```
B=[6, 9, 4, 0, 7, 10, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 11]

minimo = B[0]
indice = 0
contador = 0
for num in B:
    if num < minimo and num != 0:
        minimo = num
        indice = contador
    contador += 1

print "valor:", minimo
print "indice:", indice
```